inconsistencies in word choices
In a patent application, there is a boilerplate statement that explicitly states that the articles "a" and "an" shall mean one or more.
I am aware that the plural form of a noun, by default, also means one or more. But this default interpretation can be overridden.
If that is the case, if throughout the specifications, the phrases "a banana" and "bananas" are used, would this be interpreted to mean "one or more bananas" and "multiple bananas", respectively?
In other words, does inconsistency in word choice cause confusion?


In a patent application, there is a boilerplate statement that explicitly states that the articles "a" and "an" shall mean one or more.

Not every technique found in a patent application is necessarily a good idea.
What is the benefit of something like this? It seems even if we don't do this, the usual type of "comprising" claim will have this effect anyway:
Consider a typical claim that recites "A machine, comprising: a frob, ...". Now anything that has one frob (plus the remaining elements not shown) infringes. Furthermore, anything that has two or more frobs plus the remaining elements not shown also infringes because of the "comprising" transition. If it has two or more frobs, it still comprises a frob.
Note that there are exceptions, apparently when the nature of the invention does really require exactly one frob, and wouldn't work as well with more than one:
https://www.finnegan.com/en/insights/blogs/prosecution-first/supremely-confusing-on-that-complex-word-a-is-it-only-one-or-is-it-one-or-more.html

But this default interpretation can be overridden [...] In other words, does inconsistency in word choice cause confusion?

I recommend avoiding confusion by not overriding things in a way that singular means plural or vice versa.

Regarding your frob example? Why is it a thing that the claim is broader?

_Bear: I'm not sure what the question in this comment is exactly. One rarely wants to limit a claim to -exactly one- frob, because a trivial design around is to somehow stick in a second frob even if  the second frob is almost totally non-contributing to the function of the device.

Why is it a bad thing that the claim is broader? In other words, we seem to a agree that it is the desired outcome to cover one or more frobs. So the language that overloads "a" and "an" to be "one or more" is a good idea?

_Bear: My point is that is already the default in claim interpretation for "comprising" type claims. So one doesn't have to override the meaning of "a" and "an" in the specification to get that.

_Bear: I've reworded my answer to clarify it regarding this point.
